# Bash. синтаксическая ошибка неожиданно закончился файл

Tags: bash

не вижу ошибки в скрипте

```
#!/bin/bash
# Программа вывода страницы с информацией о системе
TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
CURRENT_TIME=$(date +"%x %r %Z")
TIME_STAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

report_uptime () {
 cat <<- _EOF_
 <H2>System Uptime</H2>
 <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
 _EOF_
 return
}
report_disk_space () {
 cat <<- _EOF_
 <H2>Disk Space Utilization</H2>
 <PRE>$(df -h)</PRE>
 _EOF_
 return
}
report_home_space () {
 cat <<- _EOF_
 <H2>Home Space Utilization</H2>
 <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
 _EOF_
 return
}
cat << _EOF_
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY>
 <H1>$TITLE</H1>
 <P>$TIME_STAMP</P>
 $(report_uptime)
 $(report_disk_space)
 $(report_home_space)
 </BODY>
</HTML>
_EOF_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Программа вывода страницы с информацией о системе
TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
CURRENT_TIME=$(date +"%x %r %Z")
TIME_STAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

report_uptime () {
 cat <<EOF
 <H2>System Uptime</H2>
 <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
EOF
 return
}
report_disk_space () {
 cat <<EOF
 <H2>Disk Space Utilization</H2>
 <PRE>$(df -h)</PRE>
EOF
 return
}
report_home_space () {
 cat <<EOF
 <H2>Home Space Utilization</H2>
 <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
EOF
 return
}
cat <<EOF
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY>
 <H1>$TITLE</H1>
 <P>$TIME_STAMP</P>
 $(report_uptime)
 $(report_disk_space)
 $(report_home_space)
 </BODY>
</HTML>
EOF
```